# Unity:Setting a Global button padding

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, padding, default

Ok, this seems like a dumb question but I've searched the UNITY docs and several forums and I cannot find a clean solution.

I've created several buttons in the unity editor and I want to adjust their padding.
I'm happy for all buttons in my GUI to use the same padding.

I can set the padding of the default GUI style in code:

```
   GUI.skin.button.padding.bottom = 30;
```

This has no effect (I assume botton's created in the editor don't use this style).

I could perhaps just create a style and just set it for every button via code but this seems a bit messy.

What's the smart way of setting your style for all buttons?
To be clear, I have created the buttons in the editor.
Thanks,
Ian

Comment: Try using `GUILayout.Space`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Presets](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Presets.html) for this. They create a default configuration for a component or asset, and then you can set in the project settings to all new created buttons to use this asset.